# Would you be flattered or offended if you were said to have 'purred'?

Tags: meaning

David Cameron was overheard by microphones saying that 'the Queen *purred*' when he gave her the result of the Scottish Referendum vote.

This is surely not literal, but a figurative use of *purr*.

I did notice that Oxford Dictionaries records a meaning 'speak in a low, soft voice, especially when expressing contentment...'.

But that is not the same as 'purring', the early 17th century origin of which word was imitative of the contented sound a cat makes.

Would people be pleased or offended at having been said to have made a sound usually reserved for cats?

Comment: David Cameron’s smug imputation of that smugness is indeed a ghastly case of rhetorical lèse-majesté after all.  When did people start ‘purring’?   http://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/shortcuts/2014/sep/24/when-did-people-start-purring

Comment: I would like to be a fly on the wall next time he goes to the Palace for an audience!

Comment: Another consideration here is the gender tilt in usage of the verb when it is applied to human beings. Though I'm too lazy to run a thorough Google Books search (which would entail winnowing out all of the cat and other nonhuman animal instances of _purred_), I'll bet that the "she [a human being] purred" matches far outnumber the "he [a human being] purred" matches. Any such tilt in usage adds a complication to assessing whether the word is or is not being used in a flattering way.

Comment: Do read the **Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions** in [an SE blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Questions shouldn't simply ask for opinions.

Comment: @SvenYargs Very good point.

Answer (score 2):

That use of *purr* compares a woman to a cat.  It is not flattering. It is old-fashioned, sexist and familiar rather than respectful. *Kitten* is a mid-20th Century pet name a man would use to address his sweetheart. *Purr like a kitten* implies that the woman is pleased with the man's attention, and specifically, that she is sexually satisfied.

Here is a figurative use from Irving Berlin's *The Girl That I Marry*, featured in the 1946 musical *Annie Get Your Gun*:

> Her nails will be polished and in her hair
>   She'll wear a gardenia and I'll be there
>   'Stead of flittin', I'll be sittin'
>   Next to her and she'll purr like a kitten.

The man singing this song is telling Annie that he does not find her attractive, because she is not submissive ---- part of the old-fashioned ideal of  femininity.

The Queen is of an age to remember this song and the intimate connotations of *purr*.

Comment: It's interesting that you mention the mid-20th century as the heyday of "Kitten" as a "pet" name for a girl or woman. The only instance I ever noticed of someone using "Kitten" as a pet name for a person was on the TV show _Father Knows Best_, which ran on TV from 1954 through 1960 and in syndication perpetually thereafter. The father in that show had two daughters: a teenager whom he nicknamed "Princess," and a preteen whom he nicknamed "Kitten." It is a fairly infantilizing nickname, isn't it?

Comment: Not to mention the term [pussycat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBdSqk78nHw). (ft. Tom Jones)